# MaterialUI label text disappearing and can not change or choose dropdown menu elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui

I need to change selected item background color without using important.I find this example in [**github**](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10771).But I need to create `MuiThemeProvider` to change background color of selected element.
(Actually I need to set it as `transparent`)

When I add `MuiThemeProvider` as a parent to `MenuItem` label text disappear and user can not choose one of menu element.In console I get an error.

**Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?**

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <Select
      id="demo-simple-select"
      displayEmpty
      value={age}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

And `theme` code

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiMenuItem: {
      root: {
        "&$selected": {
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x6tq1?file=/demo.js:315-482) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out.Actually I need to add `MuiThemeProvider` as a parent to `FormControl` not to `MenuItem`.Maybe this answer help someone.

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x6tq1?file=/demo.js:854-1288)

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <Select
      id="demo-simple-select"
      displayEmpty
      value={age}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```